# Is there any way to get data from shared Google Sheet document?

Tags: php, excel, google-sheets, google-api, google-api-php-client

I need to create a web page that has to show current prices from Google Sheets. There is a manual [https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app#protectauthcode](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/auth/web-app#protectauthcode%22OAuth%22) but it request authorisation.

Is there any way to import data every time when user open my php page, even if he doesn't have Google account? Or I need to create server-to-server communication and sync every time to json file or my DataBase by cron task?

Comment: You can r the web app as yourself and then place it in your site in an iFrame.

Comment: @Karl_S I understood the point, but can you give me more tips: how to make it remember that it is me? Somehow I have to save a key?

Comment: When you [Deploy the Script as a Web App](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web), you tell it to run as yourself.  Instructions for that and embedding it are in that link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed, here is my solution:

```
<?php
$apiKey="yourAPIkey";
include_once 'vendor/autoload.php';
$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setApplicationName("Client_Library_Examples");
$client->setDeveloperKey($apiKey);
$service = new Google_Service_Sheets($client);
$spreadsheetId = 'SheetID';
$range = 'A1:B';
$response = $service->spreadsheets_values->get($spreadsheetId, $range);
$values = $response->getValues();
if (count($values) == 0) {
  print "No data found.\n";
} else {
  print "Name, Major:\n";
  foreach ($values as $row) {
    printf("<p>%s, %s</p>", $row[0], $row[1]);
  }
}  
?>
```

[Install library](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client#download-the-release)

[Get Simple API access key](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started)